# Foldable binarytree never finishes some foldMap queries?

Tags: haskell

I've tried making a BinaryTree foldable.

This is my BinaryTree:

```
data BinaryTree2 a = Node2 a (BinaryTree2 a) (BinaryTree2 a)
                   | Leaf2
                   deriving Show
```

I've then tried to make it foldable by implementing foldMap:

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
instance F.Foldable BinaryTree2 where
foldMap f Leaf2 = mempty
foldMap f (Node2 v l r) = f v `mappend` F.foldMap f l `mappend` F.foldMap f r
```

The above compiles, but does not work unless the query can be answered by looking at the first node.

```
t3 = Node2 3 (Node2 1 Leaf2 Leaf2) (Node2 5 Leaf2 Leaf2)

foldMap (Any . (== 3)) t3
-- ghc output: Any {getAny = True}

foldMap (All . (== 3)) t3
-- ghc never returns: All {getAll =
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include the `foldMap` please, and possibly also the implementations for `treeInsert2` and `preoder`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Sorry; copy-pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: It works for me. Is there an overlap with definition of `foldMap`? Maybe `F.foldMap` will work for you too?

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks both of you. Must be something about ghc in os x (tried to let it run and it just ate all my memory). Ps. Sassa using F.foldMap did not work, but thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an instance of the Fractional Typeclass in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314929/creating-an-instance-of-the-fractional-typeclass-in-haskell) or other similar questions with indentation problems.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat precisely! when people paste the code, it is hard to tell if they forgot to indent in the code, or in the pasted content. Since `F.foldMap` refused, it means you didn't really declare `foldMap` for `BinaryTree2`. Lack of indentation meant `foldMap` wasn't an instance function, but a plain function, and when it called `F.foldMap` inside, it hung in the default implementation. But it worked for lazy monoids, like `Any`, when the top node satisfied `Any`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation. It's important.

```
instance F.Foldable BinaryTree2 where
  foldMap f Leaf2 = mempty
  foldMap f (Node2 v l r) = f v `mappend` F.foldMap f l `mappend` F.foldMap f r
-- ^^^^^^
```

It should have stumped you that you could use `foldMap` instead of `F.foldMap`.